# To which ISS astronaut(s) did Trevor Noah speak?

Tags: astronauts, public-involvement

In the Tonight Show with Jimmy Fallon video [Trevor Noah Spoke to Astronauts in Space at NASA](https://youtu.be/w11wIsrNrX8?t=131) after about `02:10`, talk show host, author and comedian Trevor Noah described touring NASA (Texas) and speaking to one or more astronauts on the ISS via voice link.

Has it been made public when this was, and with which astronauts he spoke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Orion Project's Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/NASA_Orion/status/1142499864724439041) (at Johnson Space Center) posted a picture of Noah on June 22, 2019, approximately four days before the Tonight Show clip aired.  He was on tour and had [a show in Houston that evening.](https://www.trevornoah.com/shows/2019/06/22/houston)   He also was in [Fayetteville, Arkansas for another show](https://www.trevornoah.com/shows/2019/06/21/fayetteville) the previous evening, so it seems likely that his visit was actually on the 22nd and not prior.

At the time, [Expedition 59](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_59) was on board, and it was comprised of six astronauts:

- Oleg Kononenko, commander (RUS)
- David Saint-Jacques (CAN)
- Anne McClain (USA)
- Aleksey Ovchinin (RUS)
- Nick Hague (USA)
- Christina Koch (USA)

Since Noah is something of an American cultural figure but is less known outside of North American, I would guess that it's more likely that Noah spoke with one or more of the American astronauts, a bit less likely that he spoke with Saint-Jacques, and rather less likely that he spoke with either of the Russian astronauts.  But that's really just a guess on my part.

Answer (score 3):

It happened on June 22rd of this year based on the clock in the background - GMT day 173.  Legendary GC William Foster took this picture during the event.

You can see astronauts Koch, McClain, and Saint-Jacques aligned one way, and Hague the other way. (note - ID of the males tentative! Based on looking at the crew photo [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasa2explore/40055482243/) )

[image]

Comment: Wow! So this was a real "event", much more than just "talking on the phone" as mentioned in the video.

Comment: @uhoh A lot of more or less famous people tour MCC (I have to admit I didn't know who Trevor Noah was when you posted this).  William Foster mentions visits all the time.  Hugh Jackman (even I have heard of him) visited the same week.

Comment: Late night TV has changed a lot, you know that Carson is no longer on, right? ;-)

Comment: @uhoh similar to youtube videos, I don't watch tv.

Comment: Thank goodness for YouTube; I can't even understand TV here. `+1` for not watching television!

Comment: I agree with you on the IDs of the astronauts in the picture.  (Hague is easier to recognize if you [invert the picture.](https://imgur.com/a/g35NFkA))  Note that the other two astronauts on the station were Russian, so it makes a bit of sense that they weren't included in an interview with an American TV personality.  (As an aside, I'd be interested in finding out how it's decided which crew members participate in these sorts of events—do the astronauts get a say?  Do the celebrities on the ground?)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on the IDs!

Comment: @uhoh: Johnny may be gone, but Dick Cavett *still* appears occasionally.  Maybe that gave OrganicMarble the impression that nothing has changed on late night TV.  ;^)